# SDL2 Русский текст

Tags: utf-8, кириллица, sdl

Пытаюсь вывести русский текст в SDL2 (Заголовок окна), но там в спецификации написано что [SDL_CreateWindow](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateWindow) выглядит так:

```
SDL_Window* SDL_CreateWindow(const char* title,
                             int         x,
                             int         y,
                             int         w,
                             int         h,
                             Uint32      flags);
```

> title the title of the window, in UTF-8 encoding

Как вывести русский текст в заголовке ?! Окно создаю так:

```
SDL_CreateWindow("Текст", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                         SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                         width, height,
                          SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если у Вас исходник в UTF-8, тогда всё будет работать "из коробки". Если нет, то нужно создать файл(закодированный в UTF-8), в котором держать строки, которые загружать во время исполнения. Таким образом Вы сможете передавать строки в UTF-8 в функции SDL.

Answer (score 1):

В SDL2_ttf функция для вывода текста тоже не поддерживает русский. Но там же есть функция и для вывода русского языка. Возможно, есть такая функция и для создания окна. Так же попробуйте в начале программы вставить `setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian")`.

**UPD**

Можно еще попробовать так:

```
SDL_CreateWindow("En. text", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, width, height, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
SDL_SetWindowTitle(window, "текст");
```

Думаю, **@ixSci** прав. Попробуйте собрать SDL с поддержкой UTF-8.

Comment: setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian") это для консоли но не для оконного приложения

Comment: Спасибо, учту это.